# Extra lane in heat map (pandas)

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, heatmap

Here is my [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ymrbo7v9vxpjhu/extra_line.csv?dl=0)

I plot heat map from it using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

new = pd.read_csv(r'path_to_file')
full_list=new.columns.values
new = new[full_list[1:]]
plt.pcolor(new, cmap='Blues')
plt.show()
```

File has only 11 rows of values, but for some reason 12 rows show up. Do you know what is wrong?
Here is how output looks for me:
[image: s]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. First, this has nothing to do with pandas, so we can leave that out and consider the following example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a  = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(11, 2))
plt.pcolor(a, cmap='Blues')
plt.show()
```

We create an array with 11 rows and 2 columns and plot it. It also shows a 12th row.

The easiest solution is probably to just limit the axis to the number of rows

```
plt.ylim([0,a.shape[0]])
```

in this case `plt.ylim([0,11])`.

However we want to know more... 
Is eleven special? Maybe, so let's find out by putting some other numbers in.
1 to 10 work fine. 11 won't. 12 will, 13 not.
 So what is special about those numbers, is that matplotlib cannot easily find good axes tickmarks if it is asked to plot 11, 13, ... entities.
This is decided by the matplotlib [`locator`](http://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html).
The tricky part would now be to find a good locator for 11 entities. I think there is none, as
`plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_locator( MaxNLocator(nbins = 11) )`
wont work here. But this may also be a different question now.